# Why does an additional join slow down my query by +10s?

Tags: mysql

I am doing calculations on data from several MySQL 5.7 tables with +200M rows in one of them (mks). The desired result is returned in 13s and should come down to the sub second range. Indexes are set properly as far as I can tell.

The problem seems to be the joing with the table `m` which holds the merchant names (only 20 rows). If I leave this join away the query runs in about 1.5s.

Here is my simplified query:

```
SELECT
    mks.DATE,
    m.name, -- name of merchant
    mks.merchant_id, -- id of merchant
    (SUM (
        CASE
            WHEN
               p.MANUFACTURER_ID  = 123
            THEN ((72 / mks.TEST)*0.6)
        END )
    /
    SUM (
        ((72 / mks.TEST)*0.6)
    )
    )  AS 'RESULT'
FROM mks
JOIN p on mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU
JOIN m ON mks.MERCHANT_ID = m.id
WHERE
    mks.KW_ID IN (
        264,2053,3902,5314,5315,5316,5323,5324,5506,5643,6019
    )
    AND FIND_IN_SET(mks.MERCHANT_ID, '2,1')
    AND mks.DATE = curdate() - interval  1 day
GROUP BY
   mks.MERCHANT_ID
```

EXPLAIN for query with merchant name (13s+)

```
1,PRIMARY,m,NULL,ALL,PRIMARY,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,100,Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,PRIMARY,mks,NULL,ref,"unique,keywords,mks_date",unique,2,m.id,37276,3.07,Using index condition
1,PRIMARY,<subquery2>,NULL,eq_ref,<auto_key>,<auto_key>,3,mks.KW_ID,1,100,NULL
1,PRIMARY,p,NULL,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,24,mks.ARTICLE_ID,1,100,Using where
2,MATERIALIZED,<derived3>,NULL,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2238,100,NULL
3,DERIVED,p,NULL,ref,"PRIMARY,products_index_0",products_index_0,4,const,231,100,Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
3,DERIVED,mk,NULL,ref,"PRIMARY,manufacturers_keywords_STATUS_index",manufacturers_keywords_STATUS_index,25,"const,p.SKU",9,100,Using index
3,DERIVED,mc,NULL,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,3,mk.KW_ID,1,100,Using index
```

EXPLAIN for query without merchant name (1.5s):

```
1,PRIMARY,<subquery2>,NULL,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,100,Using temporary; Using filesort
1,PRIMARY,mks,NULL,ref,"unique,keywords,mks_date",keywords,4,<subquery2>.KW_ID,1061,3.07,Using where
1,PRIMARY,p,NULL,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,24,mks.ARTICLE_ID,1,100,Using where
2,MATERIALIZED,<derived3>,NULL,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2238,100,NULL
3,DERIVED,p,NULL,ref,"PRIMARY,products_index_0",products_index_0,4,const,231,100,Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
3,DERIVED,mk,NULL,ref,"PRIMARY,manufacturers_keywords_STATUS_index",manufacturers_keywords_STATUS_index,25,"const,p.SKU",9,100,Using index
3,DERIVED,mc,NULL,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,3,mk.KW_ID,1,100,Using index
```

So far I could not figure out why this join is causing such a delay as in the end the result is simply the name of the merchant plus the coresponding result. Getting the name delays it by over 10s.

Comment: Questions that ask "why i my query low" but do not include an execution plan are hard or impossible to answer. Show the plan

Comment: What's your index and show us your execute plan.

Comment: Do you mean the output of "explain" ? I updated my question and added the output of explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET` is not as efficient as the equivalent `IN`.

You have half the answer -- Do the query *without* `merchant` as a derived table, *then* `JOIN` to `merchant` to get `name`.

Before I try to dig deeper, please check the `EXPLAIN` and the query -- I see no "derived" table in the query, yet it is in the `EXPLAIN`.  I would expect to see `FROM ( SELECT ... )` or `JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  Are any `VIEWs` involved?

Also, please provide table sizes (approx number of rows) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thank you Rick, that solved it for me. The query runs now at about 1.5s. I did a select with join on the current select. No idea why this is faster then a direct join, but it works now.